# Detect a TrueCrypt Volume

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I think I set up a TrueCrypt volume on my Win7 machine a few months ago. Now I cannot remember where I set it up or what the password might be. Is there any way that I can detect this volume? I would have maybe gave it a capacity of 2GB or thereabouts so I don't want that storage going to waste.

If I uninstall TrueCrypt, would that release the volume assigned to it?

GF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a disk utility that allows you to locate large files or sort files by size (such as [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/), although there are many others).  A file that's 2GB should stand out.

Comment: Thank you. I found a large file using windirstat and it indeed was a truecrypt volume. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Search your disk for a file with extension tc (`*.tc`).

There is no volume assigned unless you assign one (a drive letter). So you can uninstall freely.

Comment: I have searched for that file extension and cannot find it. However, if I did set up a volume and saved some files in it, surely it exists somewhere on my drive?

Comment: The 'volume' is a mounted .tc file attached to a drive letter. It must be there as a .tc file, or else try looking for large (>1GB) files. I can't think of something else...